# Mocking sessionStorage when using jestjs

Tags: reactjs, session-storage, jestjs

Ok, so I have this simple example React component that interacts with [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

```
//App.jsx    
var React = require('react/addons');

var App = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function (e) {
  },

  handleNameChange: function (e) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('name', e.target.value);
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <form>
      <input type='text' label='Name' onChange={this.handleNameChange}/>
      <button type='submit' label='Submit' onClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
      </form>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = App;
```

I've written this test for it using Jest...

```
//App-test.js
jest.dontMock('../App.jsx');
jest.setMock('sessionStorage', require('../__mocks__/sessionStorage.js'));
describe('App', function () {
  var React = require('react/addons');
  var sessionStorage = require('sessionStorage');
  var App = require('../App.jsx');
  var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

  var testapp = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <App />
  );
  var input = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(testapp, 'input');

  it('starts with empty value for name input', function () {
    expect(input.getDOMNode().textContent).toEqual('');
  });

  it('updates sessionStorage on input', function () {
    console.log(typeof sessionStorage);
    TestUtils.Simulate.change(input, {target: {value: 'Hello!'}});
    expect(sessionStorage.getItem('name')).toEqual('Hello!');
  });
});
```

and I've manually mocked sessionStorage in this last code snippet:

```
//sessionStorage.js
var sessionStorage = {
  storage: {},
  setItem: function (field, value) {
    this.storage.field = value;
  },
  getItem: function (field) {
    return this.storage.field;
  }
};
module.exports = sessionStorage;
```

The problem is, when I try to run the test, it still complains that sessionStorage is undefined. Even the call to console.log near the end of the test confirms that it is defined, but the error is thrown on the line immediately following. What am I missing here? You can clone the full project from [here](https://github.com/e-monson/jest-example.git) to see the directory structure, etc.

Comment: You are not requiring `sessionStorage` in `App.jsx`.  How are you referencing it?  I believe that Jest injects when you use `require`.

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58143066/4455570

Answer (score 19):

To solve this problem across all test cases I used this:

`npm install mock-local-storage --save-dev`

and then in you, package.json under jest configuration:

```
  ...
  "jest": {
    ...
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["mock-local-storage"]
  }
  ...
```

This will add mocked localStorage and sessionStorage for all test cases, you do not need changes in every file.
Instead of using npm package, you can also put your code in a file and specify file-location here under setupTestFrameworkScriptFile.

Your code should be similar to : https://github.com/letsrock-today/mock-local-storage/blob/master/src/mock-localstorage.js

Comment: as an update to this: "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile" has been deprecated and replaced with "setupFilesAfterEnv", which accepts an array of strings rather than a single string. See: https://github.com/mozilla/addons-frontend/issues/7506

Comment: Defining setupTestFrameworkScriptFile on package.json will throw an error for the CRA applications. Therefore you can import it as import 'mock-local-storage' in setupTests.ts.

Answer (score 13):

I am not injecting sessionStorage neither.
I was able to mock the global variable on the beforeEach function:

```js
 beforeEach(function() {
       ...
       global.sessionStorage = jest.genMockFunction();
       global.sessionStorage.setItem = jest.genMockFunction();
       global.sessionStorage.getItem = jest.genMockFunction();
       ...
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

Going off the submission from [Vishal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42705765/3919340), I installed the package:

`npm install mock-local-storage --save-dev`

But my setup was a little different so I added the equivalent to my `jest.config.js` file:

```
...
setupFiles: [
    "mock-local-storage",
    ...
]
...
```

and this seemed to resolve my issue. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Taking @afcastano solution ahead

If you want to spy storage and check the value

```js
 beforeEach(function () {
...
  jest.spyOn(window.sessionStorage, 'setItem');
...
}

it('check storage value', () => {
  expect(window.sessionStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('storage-key', 'storage-value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the context of using `jest`:

```
beforeAll(() =>
    sessionStorage.setItem(
        KeyStorage.KEY_NAME,
        JSON.stringify([Permission.VALUE_])
    )
);

afterAll(() => 
    sessionStorage.removeItem(KeyStorage.CONTEXT_TYPE_GLOBAL_PERMISSIONS)
);
```

From my understand, jest was built on top of jasmine, and jasmine allowed some form of interaction with the Browser API, hence, we need not create a storage mock from scratch.