# ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined in jest unit test case

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to write jest unit test case for one action in ReactJS  which is using session storage but I am getting error that sessionStorage is not defined.

any solution how to deal with that?

Answer (score 9):

To solve this problem you need to mock the session storage.

One simple solution is to use a plugin, like the **mock-local-storage** package (inspired by StackOverflow answers). It mocks the localStorage (and sessionStorage) for headless unit tests. Simply install it:

```
npm install mock-local-storage --save-dev
```

and then in you, `package.json` under the "jest" configuration add:

```
...
"jest": {
  ...
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "mock-local-storage"
}
...
```

This will add mocked `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` for all test cases, you do not need changes in every file.

Instead of using npm package, you can also put your code in a file and specify file-location here under setupTestFrameworkScriptFile. Your code should be similar to [this one](https://github.com/letsrock-today/mock-local-storage/blob/master/src/mock-localstorage.js).

Here's a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42705765/1333836). Credits for [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42705765/1333836).

Comment: Defining setupTestFrameworkScriptFile on package.json will throw an error for the CRA applications. Therefore you can import it as import 'mock-local-storage' in setupTests.ts.