# what is the best way to mock window.sessionStorage in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

Below is a very simple jest unit test and when running it, you will get error like

> Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined

but according to the last two comments of [this post](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2098), localStorage and sessionStorage were already added to latest JSDOM and jest. If using [jest-localstorage-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-localstorage-mock) and add it to my jest setupFiles then you will see weird error like

> TypeError: object[methodName].mockImplementation is not a function

So my question is what's the best way to mock localStorage/sessionStorage in jest. Thanks

```
describe('window.sessionStorage', () => {
    let mockSessionStorage;
    beforeEach(() => {
        mockSessionStorage = {};
        jest.spyOn(window.sessionStorage, "getItem").mockImplementation(key => {
            return mockSessionStorage[key];
        });
    });

    describe('getItem-', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            mockSessionStorage = {
                foo: 'bar',
            }
        });

        it('gets string item', () => {
            const ret = window.sessionStorage.getItem('foo');
            expect(ret).toBe('bar');
        });
    });
});
```

Below is my jest config

```
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    //setupFiles: ["jest-localstorage-mock"],
    testURL: "http://localhost/"
};
```

Answer (score 34):

Here is the solution only use `jestjs` and `typescript`, nothing more.

`index.ts`:

```js
export function getUserInfo() {
  const userInfo = window.sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo');
  if (userInfo) {
    return JSON.parse(userInfo);
  }
  return {};
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { getUserInfo } from './';

const localStorageMock = (() => {
  let store = {};

  return {
    getItem(key) {
      return store[key] || null;
    },
    setItem(key, value) {
      store[key] = value.toString();
    },
    removeItem(key) {
      delete store[key];
    },
    clear() {
      store = {};
    }
  };
})();

Object.defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', {
  value: localStorageMock
});

describe('getUserInfo', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    window.sessionStorage.clear();
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should get user info from session storage', () => {
    const getItemSpy = jest.spyOn(window.sessionStorage, 'getItem');
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify({ userId: 1, userEmail: 'example@gmail.com' }));
    const actualValue = getUserInfo();
    expect(actualValue).toEqual({ userId: 1, userEmail: 'example@gmail.com' });
    expect(getItemSpy).toBeCalledWith('userInfo');
  });

  it('should get empty object if no user info in session storage', () => {
    const getItemSpy = jest.spyOn(window.sessionStorage, 'getItem');
    const actualValue = getUserInfo();
    expect(actualValue).toEqual({});
    expect(window.sessionStorage.getItem).toBeCalledWith('userInfo');
    expect(getItemSpy).toBeCalledWith('userInfo');
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/51566816/index.spec.ts
  getUserInfo
    ✓ should get user info from session storage (6ms)
    ✓ should get empty object if no user info in session storage (1ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.548s, estimated 6s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/51566816

Comment: anything to be done to restore the original behavior of session storage at the end? Will this mock be valid only for the current test file and won't leak globally?

Comment: You probably do not even need a mock. Just use `window.sessionStorage` as usual and write your condition based on `window.sessionStorage.getItem(...)` result instead of spying `window.sessionStorage.setItem` . Simply don't forget to call `window.sessionStorage.clear()` in `beforeEach` as demonstrated.

Comment: @EricBurel This should be a good valid answer.

Comment: return `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Answer (score 18):

You probably do not even need a mock. Just use `window.sessionStorage` as usual and write your condition based on `window.sessionStorage.getItem(...)` result instead of spying `window.sessionStorage.setItem` . Simply don't forget to call `window.sessionStorage.clear()` in `beforeEach` as demonstrated.

From [Eric Burel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566816/what-is-the-best-way-to-mock-window-sessionstorage-in-jest/58143066#comment115940319_58143066)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in the context of using `jest`:

```
beforeAll(() =>
    sessionStorage.setItem(
        KeyStorage.KEY_NAME,
        JSON.stringify([Permission.VALUE_])
    )
);

afterAll(() => 
    sessionStorage.removeItem(KeyStorage.CONTEXT_TYPE_GLOBAL_PERMISSIONS)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

While mocking a whole `sessionStorage` works, you might also consider this simple approach to spy on single methods, e.g. `getItem()`:

```
describe('sessionStorage', () => {
  it('should call sessionStorage.getItem()', () => {
    const getItemSpy = jest.spyOn(Object.getPrototypeOf(sessionStorage), 'getItem');
    // Do something that calls `sessionStorage.getItem()`.
    expect(getItemSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

TypeScript version:

```
describe('sessionStorage', (): void => {
  it('should call sessionStorage.getItem()', (): void => {
    const getItemSpy: jest.SpyInstance = jest.spyOn(Object.getPrototypeOf(sessionStorage), 'getItem');
    // Do something that calls `sessionStorage.getItem()`.
    expect(getItemSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me along with adding object:

```
defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', {
   writable: true,
   configurable: true,
   value: localStorageMock
}
```